# How to convert a PDF listing the worlds ministers and cabinet members by country to a .csv in R

Tags: r, pdf

The CIA publishes a list of world leaders and cabinet ministers for all countries multiple times a year. This information is in PDF form.

I want to convert this PDF to CSV using R and then seperate and tidy the data.

I am getting the PDF from "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/world-leaders-1/"
under the link 'PDF Version for Prior Years' located at the center right hand side of the page.

Each PDF has some introductory pages and then lists the Leaders and Ministers for each country. 
With each'Title' and 'Name' being seperated by a '..........' of varying lengths.

I have tried to use the pdftools package to convert from PDF, but I am not quite sure how to deal with the format of the data for sorting and tidying.

Here is the first steps I have taken with a downloaded PDF

```
library(pdftools)


text <- pdf_text("Data/April2006ChiefsDirectory.pdf")
test <- as.data.frame(text)
```

Starting with a single PDF, I want to list each Minister in a seperate row, with individual columns for year, country, title and name.

With the step I have taken so far, converting the PDF into .csv without any additional tidying, the data is in a single column and each row has a string of text contining title and name for multiple countries.

I am a novice at data tidying any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This file is pretty messy as a text file, sometimes titles take two lines of text, or the separation between title and name is not aligned. Would you consider pre-processing in a (Linux) shell woth `pdftotext` and `awk`?

Comment: Possibly, I will do some research into that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `tabulizer` but it is going to require some work to clean it up if your want to import all the 240 pages of the document.
Here I import page 4, that is the first with info regarding the leaders

```
library(tabulizer)


mw_table <- extract_tables(
  "https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/world-leaders-1/pdfs/2019/January2019ChiefsDirectory.pdf",
  output = "data.frame",
  pages = 4,
  area =  list(c(35.68168, 40.88842, 740.97853, 497.74737 )),
  guess = FALSE
  )



head(mw_table[[1]])
#>                   X                Afghanistan
#> 1                   Last Updated:  20 Dec 2017
#> 2             Pres.               Ashraf GHANI
#> 3               CEO     Abdullah ABDULLAH, Dr.
#> 4  First Vice Pres.        Abdul Rashid DOSTAM
#> 5 Second Vice Pres.              Sarwar DANESH
#> 6  First Deputy CEO        Khyal Mohammad KHAN
```

You can use  a vector of pages that you want to import as the argument in `pages`. Consider that you will have all the country names buried among the people names in the second column. Probably you can work out a method to identifying the indexes of the country by looking for the empty `""` occurrences in the first column.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful!  What is the 'area' command doing in this case and how did you select it?
Do you have any tips on how I might save these tables as a csv file? I might be able to tidy the data a bit better that way.

Comment: The command is `extract_areas()` and it is used to select interactively the area of the table that you want to extract. Check here, the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tabulizer/vignettes/tabulizer.html) of the package and in particular the section "interactive table extraction". To save it to csv you just use  something like `write.csv(mw_table[[1]], "mydata.csv")`